# After fadeOut() the content fades back in again

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a simple modal where when you click a div with the class `day`, you will see the modal and when you click the text with the class `close` it will close.

When I try this, the modal fades in as it is supposed to, but when I click close to fade out, it fades out and then fades in again.

I tried using animate with opacity instead, hide/show, but nothing seems to solve the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.layer').hide()

  $(document).on('click', '.day', function() {
    $('.layer').fadeIn()
    $(this).children('.modal').fadeIn()
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
    $('.layer').hide()
    $(this).parent().parent('.modal').fadeOut()
  })
})
```

```css
#days {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.day {
  background-color: white;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.day:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.layer {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden!important;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 65%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
}

.modal-top {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.close {
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layer"></div>
<div id="days">
  <div class="day">
    <h2>1</h2>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-top">
        <h3>1. modal</h3>
        <p class="close">x</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <h2>2</h2>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-top">
        <h3>2. modal</h3>
        <p class="close">x</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening probably because of event bubbling. When you click close, which is is a child of element with class day, you are clicking both element with class close and day. Hence it first closes and then reopens. You can use event. stopPropagation() to stop the event bubbling to go the element with class day like this

```
    $(document).on('click', '.close', function(event){
      $('.layer').hide()
      $(this).parent().parent('.modal').fadeOut()
      event.stopPropagation()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event.stopPropagation(); this will work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.layer').hide()

  $(document).on('click', '.day', function() {
    $('.layer').fadeIn()
    $(this).children('.modal').fadeIn()
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.close', function(event) {
    $('.layer').hide()
    $(this).parent().parent('.modal').fadeOut()
    //return false;
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
})
```

```css
#days {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.day {
  background-color: white;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.day:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.layer {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden!important;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 65%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
}

.modal-top {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.close {
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layer"></div>
<div id="days">
  <div class="day">
    <h2>1</h2>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-top">
        <h3>1. modal</h3>
        <p class="close">x</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    <h2>2</h2>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-top">
        <h3>2. modal</h3>
        <p class="close">x</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```